# How do I prove that the following complex polynomial has a root?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I have given the following nonconstant complex polynomial $h(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+…+a_1x+a_0$. In the lecture our Prof. told us that using the minimal principle one could find $z\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $h(z)=0$.

So I mean $h$ is clearly an analytic function and $\Bbb{C}$ is open and path connected and thus also connected. Now I should find $z_0\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $$|f(z)|\geq |f(z_0)|>0$$ for all $z$ in the domain. Then the minimal principle sais that $f$ is constant.

My idea was now to find such a $z_0$ to apply the minimal principle and then to show that for some $w$ $f(w)=0$ Then we should also have $f(z)=0$.

But I‘m not sure if this works and therefore I wanted to ask if someone could help me and say if my idea is correct.

This would be very nice.

Comment: You only need $|f(z)|\geq |f(z_0)|$ on some open set around $z_0$. All of $\Bbb C$ is such an open set, but there could be more strategic choices.

Comment: So but I mean then i would still have $|f(z)|\geq |f(z_0)|>0$ and so it won‘t be equal to zero

Comment: So I mean Besides the proof I don‘t see how rhis should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $h(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at least $1$ and $h(z)$ has no roots.

Consider $g(z) = \frac {1}{h(z)}.$  If $h$ has no roots, $g$ is analytic.

$|g(0)| > 0$ (or else we have found a root and have a contradiction.)

Over the domain $|z| \le R$ the maximum modulus theorem says the maximum of $|g(z)|$ must lie on the circle $|z| = R$

But if as |z| gets to be large, $|h(z)|$ goes to infinity.

Hence for large enough R, $|z| = R$ implies $0<|g(z)| < |g(0)|$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: sorry I do not know the maximum modulus theorem, could one also do it with the minimal principle

Comment: You can also use almost this exact same proof and use Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The Complex numbers is a closed field in which every non-constant polynomial of degree n has n roots (sometimes repeated). The most direct route would be the Fundamental theorem of Algebra by C.F. Gauss (and perhaps others).
I am not sure of which Minimum Principle you refer to but looking in Wikipedia, there is Pontryagin’s Principle which can be Maximal or Minimal and there are Economic or Efficiency Postulates which seem either overkill or unrelated.There is Liouville’s theorem and Picard’s little theorem which describe ranges of analytic functions and when they must be constant but these would be described as ‘deep results’ in analytic function theory which would be unlikely to be taught in the same lecture that the fundamental theorem of Algebra is initially referred to or taught.